# CPU is not listet as a device using Windows

Tags: java, windows, opencl, lwjgl

My intend is to Benchmark the difference between CPU and GPU.
The problem is, I am only able to retreive my GPUs, **my CPU is not showing up**.

This program produces **correct** output on **OSX**. There, the CPU as well as the GPUs are listed:

```
public static void displayInfo() {

    for (int platformIndex = 0; platformIndex < CLPlatform.getPlatforms().size(); platformIndex++) {
        CLPlatform platform = CLPlatform.getPlatforms().get(platformIndex);
        
        System.out.println("Platform #" + platformIndex + ":" + platform.getInfoString(CL_PLATFORM_NAME));

        List<CLDevice> devices = platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL);
        for (int deviceIndex = 0; deviceIndex < devices.size(); deviceIndex++) {
            CLDevice device = devices.get(deviceIndex);
            System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, "Device #%d(%s):%s\n",
                    deviceIndex,
                    UtilCL.getDeviceType(device.getInfoInt(CL_DEVICE_TYPE)),
                    device.getInfoString(CL_DEVICE_NAME));
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

> Platform #0:NVIDIA CUDA
>
> Device #0(GPU):GeForce GTX 560 Ti
>
> Device #1(GPU):GeForce GTX 560 Ti

My PC:

- Intel i5-2500K
- Windows 8.1 pro (x64)
- 2x GeForce GTX 560 Ti

I am using `lwjgl` version 2.8.4

Why am I not able to retreive my CPU?

Comment: have you tried getting the cpu using CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU ?

Comment: yes, null is returned in this case.

Comment: System.getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER") obtains some information such as AMD64 Family 16 Model 4 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD or Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel. Then there is System.getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")

Comment: Have you installed an OpenCL CPU runtime? https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers

Comment: It was indeed a driver problem, installing the OpenCL CPU driver fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(re-posting answer from comment)

OS X is somewhat unique in the fact that it comes with OpenCL CPU drivers pre-installed, so OpenCL works 'out-of-the-box'. On Windows and Linux, you need to install an OpenCL runtime/driver for your CPU. For Intel CPUs, you can find them here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers